# Convergence in $L^2$ doesn't imply uniform convergence

Tags: real-analysis, lp-spaces, uniform-convergence

I am working on implications between different types of convergences in series of functions. I think that $L^2$ convergence doesn't imply uniform convergence, however I cannot find a counter-example. I cannot picture how a series of uniform convergent functions looks like, and this is my main issue here. Can someone give me a hint? (Both on the counter-example and on the idea of how these series look like)

Comment: **Hint :** If you can find a sequence of *continuous* functions that converge in $L^2$ to a *discontinuous* function, then the convergence won't be uniform.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe That's right! Thanks :)

Comment: Even "worse", take $f_{n,k}$ to be the [indicator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) of $\left[\frac{k-1}{n},\frac{k}{n}\right]$, then the sequence $$f_{1,1},f_{2,1},f_{2,2},f_{3,1},f_{3,2},f_{3,3},\ldots$$ converges to $0$ in $L^2[0,1]$, but doesn't converge pointwise *at any point*.

Comment: To picture uniform convergence to $f$, it's pretty much enough to picture uniform convergence to $0$ - since $f_n \to f$ iff $f_n - f \to 0$. What uniform convergence to zero looks like is a sequence of functions whose graphs look more and more like the $x$-axis as $n$ gets big. An example I like: let $g(x) = \max(0, 1 - |1 - x|)$ be a triangular spike. Consider $g_n(x) = g(nx)$. Then $g_n$ are nice and continuous, supported inside $[0, 1]$, bounded, and $g_n \to 0$ in $L^2$ and $g_n \to 0$ pointwise, but $g_n$ does not converge to $0$ uniformly!

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen this is so helpful! I really appreciate it